# ignore records hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I want to get all users which have no records in Orders Table.

Here is My Code

```
//User Model

 public function orders()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'user_id');
 }

User::all(); //query
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can have use `doesntHave` for this

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

```
User::doesntHave('orders')->get();
```